# can't install gd lib on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd

I am not able to install `gd` library on ubuntu 13.04.
When I issue the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

I gives me followiing error

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main php5-gd amd64 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main php5-gd amd64 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you know ubuntu has a dedicated stackexchange site? Its called [`askubuntu.com`](http://askubuntu.com) and your question is best suited there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail reached *end-of-life* on [January 27, 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), thus is no longer supported by Canonical and its repositories were removed from the archives.

You could try to fix the errors removing the lines from `sources.list` or replacing `raring` with `trusty` (Ubuntu 14.04) in the urls. These methods are discouraged because in one case you will not receive updates, and in the other you may install not compatible software and compromise the system.

You should should use Ubuntu 14.04, supported until April 2019. If for some reason you don't want to use that version, get Ubuntu 12.04 which is a *Long Term Support* and it's supported until April 2017.

Answer (score 0):

always try to install LTS(long term support) of any ubuntu version then you will not face these problems.

A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and always will be free of charge.
for better idea see here:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS